# Use "WHERE CURRENT OF" clause to update only the specific row on which the CURSOR is positioned in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor

I have the following cursor in SQL:

```
DECLARE @Script varchar(max)

DECLARE @getScript CURSOR

SET @getScript = CURSOR FOR

SELECT [Script]
FROM ScriptTable

OPEN @getScript
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getScript INTO @Script

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC(@Script) --Working part.  This executes the query stored in the Script column.
                      --For example INSERT INTO zTest VALUES(VAL1, VAL2, etc etc..)

        UPDATE ScriptTable
        SET DateDone = GETDATE(), IsDone = 1, Err = NULL
        FETCH NEXT
        FROM @getScript INTO @Script 
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @Err varchar(max)
        SET @Err = ERROR_MESSAGE()

        UPDATE ScriptTable
        SET DateDone = GETDATE(), Err = @Err

    END CATCH
END

CLOSE @getScript
DEALLOCATE @getScript
```

**Q1:**
Currently, I am getting the values inserted into the "zTest" table specified in my comments when I execute EXEC(@Script).

However, the second part where the "Update ScriptTable" is, updates all the rows in my Script Table.  I know I need to specify the ID for the appropriate row that the cursor is moving through.  Question is, how can I do that?  I wan't to only update the appropriate row, move to the next then update that one.

**Q2:**
My next question is, in the CATCH block, I think I am creating an infinite loop as soon as there is an error in one of the queries in the Script Column of the ScriptTable as when I look at results, it just keeps going and going.  I don't want to BREAK; the procedure as I want to write an error to the Err column and continue with the next rows till it reaches the end of @Script, then stop.

IDENT_CURRENT, Scope_Identity etc doesn't work because I haven't inserted anything into the Scripts Table.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding Q1, you have to have a primary key in order to use the cursor for updating (though there are workarounds).
In general you'll want syntax something like this:

```
update ScriptTable
 SET DateDone = GETDATE(), IsDone = 1, Err = NULL
where ID of @getScript
```

Regarding Q2, it make sense that it's an infinite loop. When you use the `TRY` and `CATCH` clauses  and it fails it doesn't execute any of the syntax in the `TRY` "area".
Therefor the `FETCH NEXT` gets skipped, and in the next loop the same error happens again.
Try to make sure there is always a `FETCH NEXT` in the loop.

Hope this helps you out a bit.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction completely.  To Update the current row where the error is found, I had to make use of the "WHERE CURRENT OF" command in SQL that I wasn't aware of.  Yes, Q2 I had to add a "FETCH NEXT FROM getScript INTO Script" to not loop into infinity.  Thank you once again @Gidil.  This really pointed me towards my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is my final code if anyone is interested:**

```
DECLARE @Script varchar(max)

        DECLARE @getScript CURSOR

        SET @getScript = CURSOR FOR

        SELECT [Script]
        FROM ScriptControl

        OPEN @getScript
        FETCH NEXT
        FROM @getScript INTO @Script

        DECLARE @Counter int = 1
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            BEGIN TRY
                EXEC(@Script)

                    UPDATE ScriptControl 
                    SET DateDone = GETDATE(), IsDone = 1, Error = NULL WHERE ID = @Counter

                FETCH NEXT
                FROM @getScript INTO @Script 

                SET @Counter = (@Counter + 1)
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
                DECLARE @Err varchar(max)
                SET @Err = ERROR_MESSAGE()

                UPDATE ScriptControl 
                SET CSC_EOD_DateDone = NULL, CSC_EOD_Err = @Err, CSC_EOD_IsDone = 0 WHERE CURRENT OF @getScript

                FETCH NEXT
                FROM @getScript INTO @Script

                SET @Counter = (@Counter + 1)
            END CATCH
        END

        CLOSE @getScript
        DEALLOCATE @getScript
```

Comment: Sorry to be critical but this doesn't seem like a great solution - you're making the assumption that the ID column on the ScriptControl table contains no "gaps" in the numbers and that the data comes out of your cursor SELECT statement in the correct order (you haven't specified an ORDER BY clause so I don't think this is guaranteed).  A better way would be to declare another variable @ScriptControlId,  include the ID column in the cursor SELECT statement, and populate this variable in the FETCH NEXT INTO. See example B here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180152(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: But I don't get it - how come you're not using `WHERE CURRENT OF` instead.  You use it in the CATCH block..!

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
DECLARE @ScriptControlId INT, @Script VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @getScript CURSOR
SET @getScript = CURSOR FOR
SELECT [ID], [Script]
FROM ScriptControl

OPEN @getScript
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getScript INTO @ScriptControlId, @Script

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC(@Script)

        UPDATE ScriptControl 
        SET DateDone = GETDATE(), IsDone = 1, Error = NULL
        WHERE ID = @ScriptControlId

        FETCH NEXT FROM @getScript INTO @ScriptControlId, @Script
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @Err VARCHAR(MAX) = ERROR_MESSAGE()

        UPDATE ScriptControl 
        SET DateDone = NULL, Error = @Err, IsDone = 0
        WHERE CURRENT OF @getScript

        FETCH NEXT FROM @getScript INTO @ScriptControlId, @Script
    END CATCH
END

CLOSE @getScript
DEALLOCATE @getScript
```

Or this:

```
DECLARE @Script VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @getScript CURSOR
SET @getScript = CURSOR FOR
SELECT [Script]
FROM ScriptControl

OPEN @getScript
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getScript INTO @Script

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC(@Script)

        UPDATE ScriptControl 
        SET DateDone = GETDATE(), IsDone = 1, Error = NULL
        WHERE CURRENT OF @getScript

        FETCH NEXT FROM @getScript INTO @Script
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @Err VARCHAR(MAX) = ERROR_MESSAGE()

        UPDATE ScriptControl 
        SET DateDone = NULL, Error = @Err, IsDone = 0
        WHERE CURRENT OF @getScript

        FETCH NEXT FROM @getScript INTO @Script
    END CATCH
END

CLOSE @getScript
DEALLOCATE @getScript
```